# epoll_create and epoll_wait

Tags: epoll

I was wondering about the parameters of two APIs of epoll.

1. epoll_create (int size) - in this API, size is defined as the size of event pool. But, it seems that having more events than the size still works. (I've put the size as 2 and forced event pool to have 3 events... but it still works !?) Thus I was wondering what this parameter actually means and curious about the maximum value of this parameter.
2. epoll_wait (int maxevents) - for this API, the maxevents definition is straight-forward. However, I can see the lackness of information or advices on how to determin this parameter. I expect this parameter to be changed depending on the size of epoll event pool size. Any suggestions or advices will be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1.

"man epoll_create"

```
DESCRIPTION
       ...
       The size is not the maximum size of the backing store but just a hint
       to the kernel about how to dimension internal structures.  (Nowadays,
       size is unused; see NOTES below.)

NOTES
       Since Linux 2.6.8, the size argument is unused, but must  be  greater
       than  zero.   (The  kernel dynamically sizes the required data struc‐
       tures without needing this initial hint.)
```

## 2.

Just determine an accurate number by yourself, but be aware that
giving it a small number may drop out the efficiency a little bit.

Because the smaller number assigned to "maxevent" , the more often you may have to call epoll_wait() to consume all the events, queued already on the epoll.